# Spectron - TypeError: app.client.getText is not a function

Tags: javascript, jestjs, electron, electron-forge, spectron

I want to create tests in my repo (https://github.com/DWboutin/jest-spectron-ts) all seems to work, but I can't access the Application.client API in my tests.

I tried in Promises style, async/await, with Mocha and I can't make it work.

This is my only test file (very basic)

```
const path = require("path");
const Application = require("spectron").Application;
const electron = require("electron");

jest.setTimeout(10000); // increase to 50000 on low spec laptop

let app: any = new Application({
  path: electron,
  args: [path.join(__dirname, "..", ".webpack", "main", "index.js")]
});

describe("test", () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    await app.start();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    if (app && app.isRunning()) {
      await app.stop();
    }
  });

  it("shows an initial window", async () => {
    const windowCount = await app.client.getWindowCount();

    expect(windowCount).toBe(1); // this gives 2, I don't know why
  });

  it("should have correct text", async () => {
    const h1Text = await app.client.getText("h1"); // TypeError: app.client.getText is not a function

    expect(h1Text).toEqual("Hello World!");
  });
});
```

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your comment about `windowCount` being `2`, see the last comment in [this section of the docs](https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron#usage).

> // Please note that getWindowCount() will return 2 if `dev tools` are opened.

I don't know if devtools are open or not, but that seems to be the official reasoning for now.

In regards to `app.client.getText` not being a function, it is because it is not a function. It actually seems the documentation is incorrect - possibly not updated from [v11.0.0 to v11.1.0](https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron/releases), and forgotten about.

> Spectron uses WebdriverIO and exposes the managed `client` property on the created Application instances. The client API is WebdriverIO's `browser` object.

Source: https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron#client

The `browser` object for WebdriverIO does not contain a `getText` function (https://webdriver.io/docs/api.html), however, an **element** retrieved does have the [`getText`](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/getText.html) function in question.

This should solve your problem:

```js
it("should have correct text", async () => {
  // because there are "two" windows...
  await app.client.windowByIndex(1);
  // use query selector to get h1
  const header = await app.client.$("h1");
  // grab the text from the element
  const h1Text = await header.getText();

  expect(h1Text).toEqual(" Hello World!");
});
```

[This unit test](https://github.com/electron-userland/spectron/blob/1510a9beddb64ca3630c143ccdc15466e17b40f5/test/web-view-test.js) on the spectron repository pointed me in the right direction for this solution.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something else that might just work for others.

You're using the wrong assertion. You want to use:

```
expect(headerText).to.equal("Hello World!");
```

Try something like this:

```
    it("Check - Header Text", async function () {
        const headerElement = await app.client.$("h1"); 
        let headerText = await headerElement.getText();
        expect(headerText).to.equal("Hello World!");
    });
```

If you come across an error with expect(), don't mind adding this as well:

```
const expect = require('chai').expect
```